# CI/CD pipeline with PostgreSQL failed with "Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified" error

Tags: postgresql, docker, pipeline

I'm using Bitbucket pipeline with PosgreSQL for CI/CD. According to this [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/test-with-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-856697462.html) PostgreSQL service has been described in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` this way:

```
definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres:9.6-alpine
```

It worked just fine until now. But all my latest pipelines failed with following error:

```
   Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
   You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD for the superuser. Use
   "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set it in "docker run".

   You may also use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust to allow all connections
   without a password. This is *not* recommended. See PostgreSQL
   documentation about "trust":
   https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
```

How can I fix it? There was no changes in `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file which could be the reason of such error..

Answer (score 25):

Looks like the reason is docker image's updates (github [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/681)). Latest versions do not allow to connect to DB without a password from anywhere. So you need to specify username/password:

```
definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres:9.6-alpine
      environment:
         POSTGRES_DB: pipelines
         POSTGRES_USER: test_user
         POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test_user_password
```

Or if you still don't want to use password, you can just set `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust` environment variable:

```
definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres:9.6-alpine
      environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

Comment: How do you open those settings?

Comment: @LukasSalich it is inside `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file.

Comment: In the end, there was a different problem with bad command for running container so it's not related.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very recent change, as of about a week ago. One way to avoid it is to hardcode your postgres version to not the latest, eg changing to `postgres:9.5.18` or `postgres:9.5.20-alpine`

Another way is to pass a fake password:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=fake_password
```

See the discussion here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/681

Answer (score 2):

If you are having issues connecting Django to PostgreSQL via Docker for the first time, then add the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust` to your `docker-compose.yml` file:

`db:
  image: postgres:11
  environment:
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust`

This solve the connection issue for me.

Please also be aware that "This is *not* recommended. See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust": https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html"

Comment: if this is NOT RECOMMENDED, why suggest it? Alerting that it is not recommended is good, but also providing why you suggest it or providing a work around over it. Will definitely help. Just an Opinion.

Comment: A good work around this is to specify a POSTGRES_PASSWORD for the superuser. You can use  "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" to set it in "docker run"

Comment: "not recommended" is for a production environment. When inside a docker and running on your local machine there is practically no concern. In fact, it makes a lot of sense!